# assigning column name to a data frame by reading a different file

Tags: r

I have created a data frame from a pre given data set which does not have column name.so by default the col names are V1, V2.......V42. Now I have one more file (.txt) which has one column with 41 rows with different name. Now the rowname of this .txt file should be the column name of my data frame. the 42nd row name of that .txt file is not given but have to assign as a "income" column name in my data frame.
how to assign column names of my data frame by taking values from .txt file and also assigning 42nd column a "income" manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 data = read.table("filename.txt", header = TRUE)
 names = c(colnames(data), "income")
 colnames(your.df) = names
```